# pear PHPunit is not working with netbeans 7

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit, pear, netbeans-7

I have installed skeletongenerator and phpunit from pear and already pointed to batch file of them in netbeans settings. but if i try to create phpunit test it shows following error. it seems like it can't find certain file. but when i installed it was being installed fine. how to fix it so that phpunit can be use with netbeans php?

> PHP Warning:  require_once(ezc/Base/base.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear\SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\autoload.php
>   on line 49 PHP Stack trace: PHP   1. {main}()
>   E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\phpunit-skelgen:0 PHP   2. require()
>   E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\phpunit-skelgen:41 PHP Fatal error: 
>   require_once(): Failed opening required 'ezc/Base/base.php'
>   (include_path='.;E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear') in
>   E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear\SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\autoload.php
>   on line 49 PHP Stack trace: PHP   1. {main}()
>   E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\phpunit-skelgen:0 PHP   2. require()
>   E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\phpunit-skelgen:41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code depends on or uses the EZ components.

You need to install the ezComponents via PEAR, too.

Comment: it is probably the `phpunit` or `skeletongenerator` that depends on it. I had installed it with --alldeps though not sure where does it messed up. After installing the `ezcomponents` it is working.